# I can't adjust my screen brightness on my Toshiba Satellite Pro C850

Tags: toshiba-laptop, brightness

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro C850 with an intel core i5 3230M cpu running Windows 10 and I cannot adjust my screen brightness. I have tried reinstalling windows, and reinstalling all of the drivers for my laptop and that didn't work either, Please help